# Vue v-for: Dynamicly fill HTML with event handler (@change) from an array into a component template

Tags: arrays, vue.js, event-handling, onchange, v-for

This is my current setup:

HTML

```
<question
   v-for="question in questions"
   v-bind:id="question.id"
   v-bind:title="question.title"
   v-bind:statement="question.statement"
   v-bind:interaction="question.interaction"
   @onchange-vg="onChangeVg"/>
</question>
```

Definition of `<question>`

```
var questionComponent = Vue.component('question', {
   props: ['id', 'title', 'statement', 'interaction', 'currentQuestion'],
   template: `
      <div :id="'question-' + id">
         <div class="flex my-3">
            <div class="py-0"><span>{{ id }}</span></div>
            <div>
               <p>{{ title }}</p>
               <div :class="{'hidden':(id !== this.$parent.currentQuestion), 'block':(id === this.$parent.currentQuestion)}">
                  <p>{{ statement }}</p>
                  <span v-html="interaction"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     `
});
```

Vue

```
var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data()  {
      return {
         vg: null,
         currentQuestion: 1,

         questions: [
            { 
               id: 1, 
               title: 'Question 1',
               statement: 'Details for question 1',
               interaction: `
                  <select ref="vb-art" @change="$emit('onchange-vg')">
                     <option disabled value="" selected>Make a choice</option>
                     <option value="red">Red</option>
                     <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                  </select>
               `
            },
            {
               title: 'Question 2',
               statement: 'Details for question 2',
               interaction: `
                  <select ref="vb-art" @change="$emit('onchange-vg')">
                     <option disabled value="" selected>Make a choice</option>
                     <option value="black">Black</option>
                     <option value="white">White</option>
                  </select>
               `
            },
         ], 

      }
   },

   methods: {
      onChangeVerguetungsart() {
         console.log("Value: " + event.target.value);
         currentQuestion++;
      },
   },
});
```

Everything is rendered fine. My problem is, that the event handler @change in `<select ref="vb-art" @change="$emit('onchange-vg')">` does not fire.

Whe I replace `<span v-html="interaction"></span>` whit the whole `<select ref="vb-art" @change="$emit('onchange-vg')">...</select>` code from `interaction` every thing works fine.

The interactions may be different from question to question. It could be an , a  or just a simple link. That's why i try to put the code into the array and not to the component definition.

How can I solve this issue, so that `<span v-html="interaction"></span>` accepts the event handler from a code snippet that is delivered by an array value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid `v-html`. v-html bind just plain HTML, not Vue directives.

For you case v-html is not necessary. Make array of options from interaction property and generate your markup by vue template.

```
interaction: [
  {value: 'red', label: 'Red'},
  {value: 'blue', label: 'Blue'}
]
```

and in your component

```
<select ref="vb-art" @change="$emit('onchange-vg')">
  <option disabled value="" selected>Make a choice</option>
  <option v-for="{value, label} in interaction" :key="value" :value="value">{{ label }}</option>
</select>
```

update:
IF you have dynamic content, then slot is your friend. (Refer docs
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html for more examples)

Your component:

```
<div>
   <p>{{ title }}</p>
   <div>
      <p>{{ statement }}</p>
      <slot />
   </div>
</div>
```

And usage

```
<question
   v-for="question in questions"
   v-bind:id="question.id"
   v-bind:title="question.title"
   v-bind:statement="question.statement"
   v-bind:interaction="question.interaction"
 >
  <select ref="vb-art" @change="onChangeVg">
     <option disabled value="" selected>Make a choice</option>
     <option value="red">Red</option>
     <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   </select>
</question>
```

Bonus is, that you don't need to emit anything.

Btw using this.$parent is also not qood idea. Your component is coupled with parent. Use props instead.

Comment: Okay, this could be a solution, but: the interactions may be different from question to question. It could be an <input>, a <select> or just a simple link. That's why i try to put the code into the array and not to the component definition.

Comment: 'Btw using this.$parent is also not qood idea.' Can you substantiate that? Because if I remove 'this.$parent.' before currentQuestion, I doesn't work, even if currentQuestion is in props.

Comment: About $parent. I mean use prop named eg 'hide' with boolean type instead of current question. This make component truly independent. Why your code is not working is propably because you missing id for second question and your handler is missing "this." at increment line

Comment: It's not possible to use boolean type, because it's kind of a question-stepper. The questions are processed one after the other by the user. So boolean is not the right choice to show/highlight the current question. The incremention is not the issue here, I just postet the code for the logic.

My only problem is that v-html doesn't handle event listeners. I have to solve that somehow na the code must come out of an array because of flexibility reason.

I'll have a look on slots, thx!